# C# Console App and Test Frameworks don't match, how to fix

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, frameworks

I wrote code in C# Console application using .NET 6.0.In order to see whether my methods are working or not I wrote a Test program. You can see the properties of my console application below.

[image: C#ConsoleAppPropertiesFramework]

So, I wrote a test program and test method. However, I can not run the test because, I cannot use the same framework with console app program. I can choose these frameworks for test program:

[image]

In my case, the test program uses .NET Framework 4.8 and the console application uses .NET 6.0
I'm trying to do unit testing. How can I fix this situation? Any help?
I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: In Visual Studio, create a new Unit Testing project (use one specific to the testing framework you're using i.e. xUnit), and select .net 6. Open up the csproj of the new project and modify your existing testing project with the details of the new one.

Comment: You cannot easily "unit test" a console application, as it is different from a class library. Tips in https://itnext.io/how-to-fully-cover-net-c-console-application-with-unit-tests-446927a4a793 might help you find the right way. You also need to learn the incompatibility between .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6, so your current attempt is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose **MSTest Tese Project** instead of Unit **Test Project(.NET Framework)**.
And then you can choose .NET 6.
[image]